# R & list.files(): list.files will not work within function?

Tags: r, csv, input

I am using Rversion 3.03 on a Windows 7 OS and am trying to solve a problem. I am not sure if this is just me being stupid or if this is really a problem with my version of R.

**Intitial problem**: I have a folder with 300+ csv files and I need to specify a function that reads in a user-specified number of files. So my idea was to use the list.files function to give me a list of the csv's and then choose from this list rather than having to reformat the user input to match the csv filenames.

```
pm <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

setwd("C:/Users/cw/Documents")
setwd(directory)

x <- id[1] 
x

files <- list.files() 

#for (x in 1:length(id))
#data[i] <- read.csv(files[x], header=T) 
#}
}
```

pm("specdata", 25:30)

So first I set the wd which works like a charm. Then I wanted to set x equal to the first element of id to obtain a starting point. Next I wanted to build a vector 'files' to choose the filenames from.

**Real problem**: if I run the 'pm'-function, R tells me that the object files does not exist. So am I doing sth wrong (obviously I am) and what?

Thanks very much,
C

Comment: I suggest you put `browser()` in first line of `pm`, run the definition of the function and step through the code, line by line.

Comment: Thanks - I did try that and couldn't see the problem there.

Comment: What actually goes wrong? If I run the code above (changing the path) it works fine for me. If the code above produces an error or warning, can you copy it. If the code above doesn't cause an error, but doesn't do what you expect, show exactly what it does, and what you expect it to do. The description at the moment suggests that you run the code above, then type `files` and get the error `Error: object 'files' not found`. If this is the case, re-read Frank Schmitt's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`files` is just a local variable that you declare inside your `pm` function. To use the results in your calling code, you should assign it to a variable (I used `filelist` here):

```
filelist <- pm("specdata", 25:30)
```

Comment: First of all sorry - I am but a newbie to programming. 

Shouldn't it be sufficient to have `files` as a local variable if I want to continue using it within the function? 

Also, I tried to call `files` directly after declaring it within the function - this also didn't work.